# Extra 0's are appended

Tags: python-3.x

I'm calculating the data if a sport is found then, data should be calculated for respective group of Names and with respective weights and if not found then '0' should be appended...

This is my code:

```
 Name_list = ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi','megha', 'varun', 'tarun','gaurav', 'geeta']

 dic1 = {
'g1': ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'], 
'g2': ['megha', 'varun', 'tarun'], 
'g3': ['gaurav', 'geeta']
 }

dic2 = {
'g1': ['hockey', 'basketball', 'football'], 
'g2': ['cricket', 'chess', 'badminton', 'carrom'], 
'g3': ['pool', 'hockey', 'tabletennis']
 }

dic3 = {
'g1': ['45', '35', '56'], 
'g2': ['67', '76', '65', '50'], 
'g3': ['8', '70', '96']
 }

for k,v in dic2.items():
    for i,l in enumerate(v):
        if l=='hockey':
           comp_list = dic1[k]
           weight = dic3[k][i]
           for name in Name_list:
                if name in comp_list:
                   a = (1*int(weight))/100
                else:
                   a = 0
                print(a)
```

The output obtained is:

```
 0.45
 0.45
 0.45
 0.45
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0.7
 0.7
```

Here, more number of zeroes are appended though there are only 9 names in Name_list....

The desired output is:

```
 0.45
 0.45
 0.45
 0.45
 0
 0
 0
 0.7
 0.7
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: 'hockey' is two times in dic2: one time in `g1` and one time in `g3`. Therefore you are processing the name list two times.

Comment: How to solve this

Comment: @PARTHKHAMAR There are lots of things you can do. Remove `'hockey'`  from one of the `dic2` lists, break out of the loops after the first time you see it, refactor your loops... Which approach you want to take depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish, which isn't clear from your question.

Comment: What I want is 'a' should be calculated with : For ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'] with wt=45 and For ['gaurav', 'geeta'], wt=70 as 'hockey' is present in 'g1' and 'g3'.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through all elements of dic 3 and all subsequents elements in their array. You have twice the "hockey" field, which means you will perform twice the loop that looks in Name_list, hence you print 2x9=18 times.